# LINQ not returning all child records

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a query in the DB:

```
SELECT  GreenInventoryBlendGradeID,bgx.blendgradeid,
        bgX.GreenBlendGradeTypeID,[Description]
  FROM [GreenInventory] gi 
 INNER JOIN [GreenInventoryBlendGradeXref] bgX 
    ON bgX.[GreenInventoryID] = gi.[GreenInventoryID] 
 INNER JOIN [BlendGrade] bg
    ON bg.[BlendGradeID]=bgx.[BlendGradeID]
```

That returns 3 records:

> TypeID  Desc
>
> ---
>
> 1      XR
>     2      XR
>     1      XF2

The LINQ:

```
    var GreenInventory = (from g in Session.GreenInventory
                    .Include("GreenInventoryBlendGradeXref")
                    .Include("GreenInventoryBlendGradeXref.BlendGrade")
                    .Include("GreenInventoryBlendGradeXref.GreenBlendGradeType")
                    .Include("GreenInventoryWeightXref")
                    .Where(x => x.GreenInventoryID == id && x.GreenInventoryBlendGradeXref.Any(bg=>bg.GreenBlendGradeTypeID > 0) )
            select g);
```

I have tried different Where clauses including the simple - (x => x.GreenInventoryID == id)
but always have only the first 2 records returned.

Any Ideas?

If I try the following:

```
var GreenInventory = (from gi in Session.GreenInventory.Where(y => y.GreenInventoryID == id)  
join bgX in Session.GreenInventoryBlendGradeXref.DefaultIfEmpty() on gi.GreenInventoryID equals bgX.GreenInventoryID  
join bg in Session.BlendGrade.DefaultIfEmpty()  on bgX.BlendGradeID equals g.BlendGradeID  
select new { GreenInventory = gi, GreenInventoryBlendGradeXref = bgX, BlendGrade = bg });
```

I Get back 3 of each objects and the correct information is in the BlendGrade objects.  It looks like the 3 GreenInventory objects are the same.  They each include 2 of the GreenInventoryBlendGradeXref objects which show the the same 2 records as before.

So I not clear on what the original problem was. Also dont know if this is the best way to resolve it.

Thanks for the answers. If anyone has a further thoughts please let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first place I'd look in would be your model and joins you have defined between the entities. You might also want to check your generated SQL statement:

`Trace.WriteLine(GreenInventory.Provider.ToString())`

or use Visual Studio IntelliTrace to investigate what was sent to the database.

Comment: I Create the Model from the existing database.

Comment: Yes, my Model from the db wasn't correctly updated to include a new primary key for GreenInventoryBlendGradeXref table.  I would mark this as the answer if I could:)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the few details you present, I would assume that you are missing a join. I have no experience with EntityFramework (I assume that you use this ORM), but as far as I know, the ".Include" tries to ensure that the set of root entities will not change and will not contain duplicates.

Your manually created query seems to indicate that there is at least one 1:n relationship in the model. The result you get from LINQ show that only distinct GreenInventory entities are returned.

Therefore you need to adjust your query and explicitly declare that you want all results (and not only distinct root entities) - I would assume that with an explicit join EntityFramework will yield all expected results - or you need to adjust your mapping.